# Cosine similarity between rows of two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2, created like this:

```
A<-c("hello", "dave", "welcome", "to", "eden")
B<-1:5
C<-6:10
DF1<-data.frame(A,B,C)

D<-c("do", "you", "want", "this", "book")
E<-11:15
F<- 16:20
DF2<-data.frame(D,E,F)
```

Essentially, columns 2 and 3 are dimensions of the word in column 1. I want to compute cosine similarity of each word in DF1 to each word in DF2 and store it in a tabular form. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with fuzzy join package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)


A<-c("hello", "dave", "welcome", "to", "eden")
B<-1:5
C<-6:10
DF1<-data.frame(A,B,C)

D<-c("do", "you", "want", "this", "book")
E<-11:15
F<- 16:20
DF2<-data.frame(D,E,F)

DF1 %>% 
  stringdist_full_join(DF2, by = c('A' = 'D'), 
                       method = "cosine", 
                       distance_col = "distance")
```

It gives

```
         A B  C    D  E  F  distance
1    hello 1  6   do 11 16 0.7327388
2    hello 1  6  you 12 17 0.7817821
3    hello 1  6 want 13 18 1.0000000
4    hello 1  6 this 14 19 0.8110178
5    hello 1  6 book 15 20 0.6913933
6     dave 2  7   do 11 16 0.6464466
7     dave 2  7  you 12 17 1.0000000
8     dave 2  7 want 13 18 0.7500000
9     dave 2  7 this 14 19 1.0000000
10    dave 2  7 book 15 20 1.0000000
11 welcome 3  8   do 11 16 0.7642977
12 welcome 3  8  you 12 17 0.8075499
13 welcome 3  8 want 13 18 0.8333333
14 welcome 3  8 this 14 19 1.0000000
15 welcome 3  8 book 15 20 0.7278345
16      to 4  9   do 11 16 0.5000000
17      to 4  9  you 12 17 0.5917517
18      to 4  9 want 13 18 0.6464466
19      to 4  9 this 14 19 0.6464466
20      to 4  9 book 15 20 0.4226497
21    eden 5 10   do 11 16 0.7113249
22    eden 5 10  you 12 17 1.0000000
23    eden 5 10 want 13 18 0.7958759
24    eden 5 10 this 14 19 1.0000000
25    eden 5 10 book 15 20 1.0000000
```

But as you said below, you want to calculate vector cosine and not stringsim cosine so you can do something like:

```
DF_full <- DF2 %>% 
  mutate(id = 1) %>% 
  inner_join(DF1 %>% mutate(id = 1), by = 'id') %>% 
  mutate(vector_word_1 = purrr::map2(B,C, c),
         vector_word_2 = purrr::map2(E,F, c)) %>% 
  mutate(cosine_sim = purrr::map2(vector_word_1, vector_word_2, lsa::cosine))
```

```
 DF_full
      D  E  F id       A B  C vector_word_1 vector_word_2 cosine_sim
1    do 11 16  1   hello 1  6          1, 6        11, 16  0.9059667
2    do 11 16  1    dave 2  7          2, 7        11, 16  0.9479735
3    do 11 16  1 welcome 3  8          3, 8        11, 16   0.970496
4    do 11 16  1      to 4  9          4, 9        11, 16  0.9831082
5    do 11 16  1    eden 5 10         5, 10        11, 16  0.9904049
6   you 12 17  1   hello 1  6          1, 6        12, 17  0.9006583
7   you 12 17  1    dave 2  7          2, 7        12, 17  0.9439612
8   you 12 17  1 welcome 3  8          3, 8        12, 17  0.9674378
9   you 12 17  1      to 4  9          4, 9        12, 17  0.9807679
```

In your second comment, you note, what to do when vector length is 100 for instance, maybe:

```r
df_1 <- tibble(A = rep(A, each = 100), 
               B = rnorm(500)) %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(B = list(B))


df_2 <- tibble(D = rep(D, each = 100), 
               E = rnorm(500)) %>% 
  group_by(D) %>% 
  summarise(E = list(E))

DF_full <- df_2 %>% 
  mutate(id = 1) %>% 
  inner_join(df_1 %>% mutate(id = 1), by = 'id') %>% 
  mutate(cosine_sim = purrr::map2_dbl(B, E, lsa::cosine))
```

Comment: @ Guillaume , I just wanted to check the cosine values, and ran this code:   

                                  
    `hello<-DF1 %>% 
    filter(A=="hello") %>% 
    select(-1) %>% 
    t %>% 
    as.vector()


do<-DF2 %>% 
    filter(D=="do") %>% 
    select(-1) %>% 
    t %>% 
    as.vector()
lsa::cosine(hello,do)`

I got output as 0.9059667 which is different than 0.7327 that the above output indicates. I am wondering why the discrepancy?

Comment: Yes you're right, I have misunderstood your question. I have edited my answer to give a solution I think

Comment: that worked. In this example, there are only two dimensions (B,C for DF1 and E,F for DF2), if we have, say 100 dimensions, how would that change the solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the second code is also fine but I was thinking of the datasets like these:

A<-c("hello", "dave", "welcome", "to", "eden")
B<-1:5
C<-6:10
D<-7:11
E<-8:12
G<-10:14
H<-11:15
DF1<-data.frame(A,B,C,D,E,G,H)

I<-c("do", "you", "want", "this", "book")
J<-11:15
K<- 16:20
L<-17:21
M<-12:16
N<-1:5
O<-9:13
DF2<-data.frame(I,J,K,L,M,N,O)
where each dimension has a unique variable name. In your code, the 100 dimensions are represented by B and E, allowing you to use map2

Comment: Yes it was just an example to show this solution: it works. You can wrap your data into this shape I think it’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(DF1, row.names = 1)# convert the first column words as row names
DF2<-data.frame(DF2, row.names = 1)# # convert the first column words as row names

library(dplyr)
DF1 <-DF1 %>% 
    as.matrix() ## convert from dataframe to matrix
DF2 <-DF2 %>% 
    as.matrix() ## convert from dataframe to matrix

library(word2vec)
word2vec_similarity(DF1, DF2, type = "cosine")
```